# Setting default value for a nested model table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, has-many, belongs-to

I got two models in my app: Post and Review, nested in Post. They both has belong_to relation with User model used by Devise gem. All relations seem to be correct there.
The problem is that when I want to get Post author, I can do it as I wrote this in my Post controller(create method):

```
@post.user_id = current_user.id
```

But I did it fpr reviews as well:

```
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:postl_id])
@review = @post.reviews.create(review_params)
@review.user_id = current_user.id
redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

Still I do not see any data in user_id column in Reviews table when I create review.

Show me please where am I wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@review = @post.reviews.create(review_params.merge({:user_id => current_user.id}))
```

Comment: Expanding on this: The problem is that you are not saving `@review` after setting `user_id`

Comment: @DickieBoy but OP says he does not see any data in `user_id` that means other columns are having data. so he must have skipped to paste the save line here

Comment: That worked. I knew I was missing something, thank You both for showing me what exactly.